# How to check dynamically-constructed variable names in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am console logging a string using a `for loop` and appending the for loop index number to each string. However, if the string matches the variable name `roastAboutCheapLvl1` that I have defined, I want the variable content to be displayed instead.

What I have tried so far:

```js
var roastAboutCheapLvl1 = "it works";

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var num = [i].toString();
  var a = "roastAboutCheapLvl" + num;
  console.log(a);
}
```

What I expected:

```
it works   
roastAboutCheapLvl2  
roastAboutCheapLvl3  
roastAboutCheapLvl4   
roastAboutCheapLvl5
```

---

What am I doing wrong in the above attempt?

Comment: So, use the variable name instead of a string.

Comment: do it like this console.log(roastAboutCheapLvl1);

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: maybe you are looking for an object containing your values `{ "Lvl1": "foo", "Lvl2": "bar" }` and then access them with your `a` variable. However I just guessed that, your question is not clear enough for a real answer

Comment: i think you should google it first

Comment: I am pretty sure you are trying to create variable names dynamically (i.e. concat two strings to create an existing variable name), and then test if that dynamically-created variable name currently exists. If so, see my answer.

Comment: @mhdHD - Have any of the below answers solved your problem? If so, please choose a correct answer so the question will be closed. If not, please edit your question (or post a comment below one of the answers) to tell us what you need.

Comment: @mhdHD Did you choose the wrong answer? Please confirm you are **not** trying to build the variable name "on the fly" (i.e. inside the for loop), because the selected answer does not do that - it requires that you spell-out the var name in full for testing/analysis. Also note that the ternary operator is still an if statement, just using a different (single-line) format - so you will need to use one if statement (or ternary statement) for each variable name you wish to build/test in the for loop. *Also, notice that to get the `Object.keys()` info, the full var name was written, not built*

Answer (score 0):

I think you are inquiring about creating dynamic variables in javascript. See this example for how to do it.

```js
var roastAboutCheapLvl1 = "it works (1)";
var roastAboutCheapLvl3 = "it works again (3)";

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var aa = window['roastAboutCheapLvl' + i];
  if (!aa){
    console.log('roastAboutCheapLvl' + i);
  }else{
    console.log(aa);
  }
  
}
```

See this answer for explanation:

[Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the `roastAboutCheapLvl1` variable to an object which will convert the variable to a `key: value` pair and then retrieve the key from the object.

Add a second `if statement` inside your `for loop` that checks if the variable name matches the `a` and if it does, return the variable else return `a`.

---

Check the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I described:

```js
    var roastAboutCheapLvl1 = "it works";

    let varName = Object.keys({roastAboutCheapLvl1})[0];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      var num = [i].toString();
      var a = "roastAboutCheapLvl" + num;
      if (a === varName) {
          console.log(roastAboutCheapLvl1);
      } else {
          console.log(a);
      }
      
    }
```

Or if you don't want to use an `if/else statement`, you can use a `ternary operator` instead like this:

```js
        var roastAboutCheapLvl1 = "it works";

        let varName = Object.keys({roastAboutCheapLvl1})[0];;

        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
          var num = [i].toString();
          var a = "roastAboutCheapLvl" + num;
          a === varName ? console.log(roastAboutCheapLvl1) : console.log(a);
        }
```

Comment: You are hard-coding the variable name that you console.log, so this is not a truly dynamic solution. There is a simpler, more correct way to do this.

Comment: @Gibberish Agreed, Let me try fiddling with the code a bit more. Btw, using `window['roastAboutCheapLvl' + i]` might not be a good idea if there are more than one variable with the same name defined locally in some other function.

Comment: is there any chance to do that without using the if statement??

Comment: @mhdHD Yes, you can use a ternary operator instead. Let me add the approach as an alternative in the answer.

Comment: @mhdHD I have updated the answer to show you how you can replace the five-line `if/else statement` with a one-line `ternary operator`.

Comment: how can speak to you in private ?? (i'm new in stack overflow)

Comment: @mhdHD There is no private chat system in StackOverflow at the moment. Can I know why you need to message to me in private? If it is work-related, I can provide you with an email or a link where you can contact me.

Comment: Bc, that is not my real problem. That is a clone of my problem although, you make it more difficult to do it

Comment: The ternary operator approach is just two lines extra to your current code. I don't understand how that is difficult. What exactly do you have to do in the original code?

Comment: give me ur email ,i can't post my current code on stack overflow

Answer (score -1):

I understand what you are trying to do, but you are declaring the variable the wrong way round

When you declare a variable you create what is called a namespace which holds a value.

For example, look at:

```
var MyFirstVariable = "Hi this is my first variable"
```

The variable's **name** is MyFirstVariable

The **value** of MyFirstVariable is "Hi this is my first variable"

So in order to get your code to work the way you expect you need to write it like this:

```js
    var myVariable = "roastAboutCheapLvl1";
    
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      var a = "roastAboutCheapLvl" + i.toString();
      if (a === myVariable){
         console.log(a);
      }
    }
```

Personally i would write it like this:

```
const myVariable = "roastAboutCheapLvl1";
```

(you can use const because the variable is **constant** you are using it to compare something to, it will not be changed or reassigned)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you are addressing the nature of the OP question.  Per my reading, the OP is asking how to construct different variable names in a for loop, see if each variable exists, and if so, print its contents. You are checking if the contents of a specified variable are the same as a string that is constructed in the for loop. There is some similarity, but not quite what the question is asking, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @mhdHD - OP, please confirm our understanding of your question . . . ? *If HappyMachine is correct, then I have misunderstood the question and should remove my own answer...*